# Tailwind CSS: How do you apply an extended colour in an @layer?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have markup coming from a server so I can't change it: `<h1>Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong></h1>`

I require the `strong` elements to be `boring-green`, and I have extended the colors to add it, however when I go to apply it I get an error:

> The boring-green class does not exist. If boring-green is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a @layer directive.`.

How do I use an extended colour in a layer?

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    module.exports = {
      theme: {
        extend: {
          colors: {
            'boring-green': {
              DEFAULT: '#038C33',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**globals.css**

```css
    @layer base {
      
      h1 {
        @apply text-2xl uppercase font-light leading-none ;
      }
    
      h1 strong {
        @apply boring-green;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks fine in your `tailwind.config.js`, the only thing wrong is that you missed the color prefix in `global.css`:

`[prfixName]-boring-green`

For example: `text-boring-green`, `bg-boring-green`, `border-boring-green`.

```css
/* This will work */
h1 strong {
   @apply text-boring-green;
}
```

Comment: can't see the wood for the trees!

Answer (score 0):

first try add `boring-green` to any element as a classname, if it not work in this case the issue will be in **tailwind.config.js**, try:

```
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'boring-green':'#038C33',
      }
    }
```

if it work in this case the issue will be in **global.css**, Sorry, i don't know how to fix it from CSS

Answer (score 0):

To apply a custom colour (defined inside the Tailwind config file) in `@layer`, try to use the `@config` directive in your App's CSS file, so that Tailwind will use it when compiling that CSS file.

To do so, you need to add this line to your app's CSS file before `@tailwind base`, `@tailwind components` and `@tailwind utilities`:

```
@config "../tailwind.config.js"; /* correct the relative path to your tailwind config file if needed/*
```